# Mongosh not printing command output

Tags: mongodb, powershell

With mongo 4.4, I'm having an issue printing command outputs with the new mongosh shell

When I open the shell directly from windows command/powershell and run a command, this prints an acknowledgement like below:

```
...mongosh <connectionstring>
db.test.deleteMany({})
{Acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1000}
```

However I had to **manually** run every step above. I tried to script everything, e.g. connect to mongosh through a powershell script and put my db commands in a javascript file, and while the command does run correctly I no longer get the acknowledgement output printed in powershell/command line

```
Powershell script:
...mongosh <connectionstring> script.js

Javascript file:
db.test.deleteMany([])
```

How do I print the acknowledgement?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?  Did you try `--verbose`?  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/options/

Comment: @Tim Roberts adding --verbose didnt provide anything extra. Same result. One workaround i found was surrounding my db command in a print() command i.e. print(db.test.deleteMany([])) and this does print the acknowledgement however this means I will always have to add print to every command I use

Comment: That's pretty typical behavior for an interpreter shell.  Python works the same way.

Comment: @Tim Roberts is there any other way to print the output back without needing to surround every dB command in a print statement?

Comment: No.  Once you have a real script, rather than a live interpreter session, you have to explicitly print the things you want to see.